# Open Settings app from Today Extension/Widget?

Tags: ios, swift, today-extension

Is it possible to directly open the Settings app from the widget/today extension?

I have tried the following code, but sadly it is not working

```
let url = URL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!
extensionContext?.open(url) { _ in }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code should be work

```
        guard let url = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) else {
            return
        }
        extensionContext?.open(url, completionHandler: { (success) in
            if !success {
                var responder = self as UIResponder?

                while (responder != nil){
                    let selectorOpenURL = NSSelectorFromString("openURL:")
                    if responder?.responds(to: selectorOpenURL) == true {
                        _ = responder?.perform(selectorOpenURL, with: url)
                    }
                    responder = responder?.next
                }
            }
        })
```

however I'm not sure what "additional review" means 
[image]

Comment: For some reason this code opens the settings app and puts it in the background if the settings app is not already opened. But if the settings app is opened manually before tapping on the widget and then you tap on it, the app will open correctly